# Creating a web application that can be accessed both online and offline

Tags: c#, html, web

I am newbie to the web programming. I have been working as desktop application programmer for the last 8 years. Now one of my projects is to create a web application using HTML 5 and some java script that can be live on the cloud as well as downloadable as a desktop application to work offline. I don't need any database to store any data. I am thinking of writing a C# win form application with a web browser control to load the HTML pages and the `.js` files.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to achieve? if so, is there any other way than what I mentioned above?
2. What about the security concerns such as accessing the files(the html files, java script files, etc)? Whether this can be called into my application from the local hard disk?
3. If I can run it as a desktop application, how to make sure that the source code is not accessed by anyone in the client machine?

Comment: How about Silverlight (and running it Out-of-Browser)?

Comment: I thought about it Brad Christie, but my application is more of calculations for which HTML and java scripts are the best bet.

Comment: If your web application is made of only html, css and javascript, then all the files are made available to be downloaded anyway so they can be rendered/run on a local browser. Adding a windows form with a web component would be no different than just running from within a browser.

Comment: Thanks Scampbell. I see what you mean. My idea was to write the HTML, CSS and the Java script and publish it on the cloud as an online application. To make use of this as a standalone application (for different customer who doesn't have net connection) create the win form app.

Comment: If the web server is IIS with ASP.NET, then your application logic could live in a DLL assembly that generates the HTML and the JavaScript on the fly and sends it to the browser / browser control in case of the desktop app (maybe using memory stream to put and then read the code). This would need more initial effort, but you will write the code creation part only once and it will be the same for web and desktop using the same technology.

Comment: Thanks Pasty. It is clearer now. I shall try your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's achievable, but why you would want to wrap it in a C# web browser control doesn't really make sense to me. With HTML5 you can define cache manifest files to create offline apps that run in any browser that supports it, no need to wrap it with anything as long as the client has a capable browser. They don't even have to know it's an offline app!
2. Not quite sure what you mean here with regards to security concerns. That's a massive topic. Just use common sense and realize that anything you store on their computers will be accessible by them (e.g. do not give them your public/private key pair or store any passwords or anything you don't want them reading in the files you're sending to them) and use a secure connection to send sensitive data back and forth between the client and your server.
3. You really can't prevent anyone from accessing the source code if it's on their machine. The best you can do is obfuscate it to a reasonable degree before deployment to make it harder on the person trying to read it.

Comment: Thanks BoredBlazer. Your answer makes more sense to me. However could you throw a little more light on the cache manifest files? Some links for tutorials would be useful.

Comment: About number 3.: basically that is right, but IMO the effort to decompile and understand a binary file is bigger, than understanding and reading plain HTML / JavaScript, so it can't be compared so easily.

Comment: Here's a [Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) about it. Basically HTML5 introduced a standard called the application cache that allows 100% uptime to your web app as long as the client has accessed it once. They'll always hit the same URL for the web app, but if you haven't updated it, the server is down, or their network is down it'll act as an offline app. When you update the app just update the cache manifest file and next time they visit BOOM they get an updated application.

Comment: @pasty I agree with you there, but since he stated that it's also going to be an online app it really won't be more secure by wrapping it in a compiled app that generates the HTML dynamically. The client will be able to observe the html/javascript content being delivered to them either way.

Comment: Not entirely true, because the web browser component can be configured not to allow showing context menu and thus the source code! And the OP stated that he want to create a Windows Form app with Browser control in it.